# Implementing Haskell's `union`

Tags: haskell, reinventing-the-wheel

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#loading-modules) shows the `union` function:

> union also acts like a function on sets. It returns the union of two
>   lists. It pretty much goes over every element in the second list and
>   appends it to the first one if it isn't already in yet. Watch out
>   though, duplicates are removed from the second list!

Example:

```
ghci> [1..7] `union` [5..10]  
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Please critique my implementation.

```
import Data.List (nub)

union' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
union' xs ys = nub (xs ++ ys)
```

This 1-line implementation seems easy to understand, however I'm concerned at its bad/mediocre performance. Consider that I'm appending `xs` to `ys`, and then performing `nub` on the whole list.

Comment: This is wrong, but not for any good reason. `union`'s behavior is weird. The key is in that last sentence of the quote, what it elides is that duplicates are *not* removed from the first list. Unless you change data structures or impose an `Ord` constraint, the performance won't get any better either.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you please critique my updated version?

Comment: Rolled back to Rev 1. To request a review of your revised code, [please ask a separate question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1763/9357).

Answer (score 2):

The formatting of your code is broken, so I've reproduced it here for clarity.

```
union' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
union' xs ys = xs ++ union'' ys xs
    where union'' [] _         = []
          union'' (a:as) first = if (a `elem` first) then union'' as first else a : union'' as (a:first)
```

Your code is correct, but can be rewritten to exhibit better style.

```
module MyUnion where

import qualified Data.List as List (union) -- For testing with QuickCheck

union :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
union xs ys = xs ++ union' ys xs
    where union' []       skips                   = []
          union' (y':ys') skips | y' `elem` skips =      union' ys'     skips
                                | otherwise       = y' : union' ys' (y':skips)
                             -- ^ Guards instead of ifs
                                               -- ^ Aligned for readability

prop_equal xs ys = union xs ys == List.union xs ys -- QuickCheck-able property
```

Good Haskell style also involves using higher-level functions whenever other considerations don't require otherwise (e.g., performance, comprehensibility). Here's my version of `union`, note that it looks much more like your version from before the edits.

```
union xs ys = xs ++ filter (`notElem` xs) (nub ys)
```

For reference here is the definition of `unionBy` from `base` (`union` is defined as `unionBy (==)`).

```
unionBy                 :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
unionBy eq xs ys        =  xs ++ foldl (flip (deleteBy eq)) (nubBy eq ys) xs
```